# Postgres table column looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Movie Review` table with `approve` column thats a *`boolean`*. Would I be able loop through each reviews and see if any of the reviews are *`true`*?

If any(at least one) the reviews are approved (*`true`*), then display it, else display `<p>No reviews at the moment...</p>`

So far I have this..I know this only check if any review are in the database and not if they are *`true`* or *`false`*. Not sure how to get it right.

```
<% if !@movie.reviews.present? %>
   <p>No reviews at the moment. Be the first!</p>
<% else %>
  <% @movie.reviews.each do |review| %>
    <%= render "/reviews/review" , review: review%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
<% unless @movie.reviews.where("reviews.approve = ?", true).present? %>
   <p>No reviews at the moment. Be the first!</p>
<% else %>
  <% @movie.reviews.each do |review| %>
    <% if review.approve %>
      <%= render "/reviews/review" , review: review%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked! Also i was wondering is it good practice to write it like this in html.erb file or should move to controller?

Comment: @Tim I would prefer to move the query from view template to `Movie` model.